# Is there a module to modify messages?

Tags: 7

I am looking out to change the message displayed after user registration submits the user details. Is there a module to achieve it, or do we need to hard code the message to display?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).  It will work with any string that is handled in the proper manner (ie, it is run through [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)), not just messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're probably looking for is a way to redirect the user to a custom page after they register. Check out the [Logintoboggan module](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) which gives you the option of where to send the user after they register.